# phonegap select options issue in webview on Android 6.0

Tags: android, select, webview

I have problem perform in webview on Android 6.0:
Create an app with an select box dropdown list and see on the webview android 6.0,
when we open select box style on android native, choose an option, the select box closed, but it doesn't update selected option. And we open it in the 2nd time, choose an option, it works fine.

I looking for some around and see it seems issue an webview on android 6.0, we need to choose twice times option on select box.

Tested on Samsung S5, android 5.0 : Works good.

Tested on Samsung S6, android 6.0 : Not Work.

Here is sample code:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looking around and found this code to fix the problem:

> var allSelectElements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
>
> for (var i = 0; i < allSelectElements.length; i++) {
>       allSelectElements[i].addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
>           //This is the important line
>           $(this).focus().click();
>           //e.stopPropagation();
>
> }, false);
>   }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jquery_mobile_1.4.0 , removing **data-position="fixed"** in **data-role="header"**  solved my problem.